# How lambda function in unfoldr can be used with two arguments in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, types, lambda, functional-programming, unfold

When reading [this article](https://wiki.haskell.org/The_Fibonacci_sequence#With_unfoldr) I found example of generating Fibonacci sequence with `unfoldr` function:

```
fibs = unfoldr (\(a,b) -> Just (a,(b,a+b))) (0,1)
```

But when I looked at [documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:unfoldr) I found that lambda in `unfoldr` function takes only one argument `b`:

```
unfoldr :: (b -> Maybe (a, b)) -> b -> [a]
```

Examples in the doc also demonstrate only one argument usage:

```
unfoldr (\b -> if b == 0 then Nothing else Just (b, b-1)) 10
```

So, I'm interested how can it be applied to two arguments as in Fibonacci example?

Comment: Hint: replace `b` with `(b, c)` in the type signature of `unfoldr` and see what happens.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is your function:

```
GHCi> let foo = \(a,b) -> Just(a,(b,a+b))
```

While we can certainly interpret it in our heads as a function of two arguments, as far as Haskell is concerned it only takes one argument...

```
foo :: Num t => (t, t) -> Maybe (t, (t, t))
```

... a *pair* of type `(t, t)` for some `t` in the `Num` class. All that is going on in your example, then, is that the `b` in `unfoldr`'s signature is being replaced by `Num t => (t, t)`, and `a` by `Num t => t`, resulting in:

```
Num t => ((t, t) -> Maybe (t, (t, t))) -> (t, t) -> [t]
```

Some extra evidence of that:

```
GHCi> :t unfoldr (\(a,b) -> Just (a,(b,a+b)))
unfoldr (\(a,b) -> Just (a,(b,a+b))) :: Num a => (a, a) -> [a]
```

---

With your immediate question answered, here is a little digression. Another way of passing two arguments to a Haskell function is passing them separately, as opposed to in a pair:

```
GHCi> let foo2 a b = Just(a,(b,a+b))
GHCi> :t foo2
foo2 :: Num t => t -> t -> Maybe (t, (t, t))
```

Obviously, if you still have `foo` around you don't even need to rewrite the implementation:

```
GHCi> let foo2 a b = foo (a, b)
GHCi> :t foo2
foo2 :: Num t => t -> t -> Maybe (t, (t, t))
```

In fact, this transformation -- which in jargon is called *currying* -- is *always* possible, and there is even a function for doing that...

```
GHCi> let foo2 = curry foo
GHCi> :t foo2
foo2 :: Num t => t -> t -> Maybe (t, (t, t))
```

... as well as another one for going in the opposite direction:

```
GHCi> :t uncurry foo2
uncurry foo2 :: Num t => (t, t) -> Maybe (t, (t, t))
```

What might be surprising in all that, however, is how even `foo2`, which looks even more like a function of two arguments than `foo`, still is a function of one argument! The trick is that a signature like that of `foo2`...

```
foo2 :: Num t => t -> t -> Maybe (t, (t, t))
```

... has some omitted, optional parentheses. The omission conceals the fact that the function arrow, `->`, is right-associative. If we add them, we get:

```
foo2 :: Num t => t -> (t -> Maybe (t, (t, t)))
```

That is, `foo2` takes one argument (that is, our first argument) and returns another function which also takes one argument (that is, *our* second argument).

---

The main takeaway, then, is that **all Haskell functions take just one argument**. Fortunately, it is very easy to write functions that work as if they took two arguments. More often than not, that is done by writing the function in a curried way (that is, as a function like `foo2` that returns another function), but sometimes it is necessary or convenient to pass multiple values in a pair, as you had to do in your example.

Answer (score -1):

First, unforldr aplied to func ((a,b) -> Just (a, (b, a+b)))

returns a function b -> [a]. This is a currying.

Then the result function is applied to the second argument (0, 1)

which ends a final result.